# Replacing vanilla wafers in rum balls

Tags: substitutions

I have a coworker with a dairy/whey sensitivity, yet I love making rum balls around this time of year and plan on bringing a batch to work.

Are there any close substitutions I can use in place of wafer crumbs that will stay fairly true to the original recipe?

Comment: I've seen recipes without dairy or "whey"; can' you just switch recipe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graham crackers should work well for you. I have used graham crackers and vanilla wafers interchangeably for several recipes. There are rum ball recipes that list several different crushed cookie options (using the same volume of each.)

Answer (score 4):

I have vegan friends who love my rum ball recipe (which also calls for vanilla wafers).  I've had great success using a vegan snickerdoodle crisp that I found at the store.  Anything sufficiently crunchy without too-overpowering a flavor should be fine.